# Адаптация верстки под retina

Tags: html, css, css3

Необходимо сверстать адаптивный сайт с учетом качественного отображения на экранах с retina.

Примеров, как адаптировать под это дело изображения, валом и вроде вопросов не возникает. Не понимаю одного: почему текст с размером шрифта в 32px на экране iPhone весьма и весьма велик, хотя насколько я понимаю, учитывая двойню плотность пикселя шрифт должен вроде как уменьшиться? Приемлемого результата достигаю только в случае уменьшения шрифта в два раза.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я не так делаю?

в HTML прописываю метатег:

```
meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

в CSS я родительскому элементу задаю базовый размер шрифта

```
html, body {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

а дальнейшие размеры шрифтов задаю в относительных единицах em:

```
.text {
    margin-right: 2em;
    margin-left: 2em;
}
```

В итоге на iPphone смотрится очень убого и приходится использовать следующую конструкцию:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 568px), 
screen and (-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 568px),
screen and (-ms-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 568px),
screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 568px),
screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 568px) {
html, body {
        font-size: 8px;
    }
/**
 * и далее уменьшаю все размеры в 2 раза,
 * что в px, но как я понимаю такого быть не должно
 */
}
```

И вроде смотрится норм... Подогнал, проверил, но проблема в том, что мне еще надо и сверстать под iPad, а вот его у меня нету и черт его знает, как правильно сверстать. В наличии только iPad 2 без ретины.

Я так понимаю все надо вручную перебивать. Размер в 70px огромный как на обычном устройстве, так и почему-то на устройствах с retina.

Проверял. Создал блок в 640px и на iPhone 5 (разрешение 640 на 960). Он создал мне горизонтальную прокрутку размером на два экрана.

Comment: Размеры CSS-пикселей на устройствах с Retina ополовинены.    
Иначе говоря, блок в 320px займет всю ширину экрана iPhone.  
Не нужно менять размеры шрифтов под Retina дисплеи.  
Нужно подгружать картинки двойного размера  
http://habrahabr.ru/post/150071/

Comment: вот вы говорите что 320px займет всю ширину экрана при условии что физическое расширение экрана составляет 640х960, т.е. получается как бы размер блока физически увеличивается в 2 раза и я так понимаю, что если хочу отобразить шрифт высотой в 12рх (на десктопе) то для ретины я должен указать 6рх?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как нет примеров верстки, то могу только предположить пару вариантов.

Во первых, возможно у вас просто не согласованы размеры макета и реального вида этого макета на экране, поэтому беря размеры из файла вы получаете не верные размеры шрифтов и блоков.

Если у вас макет для мобильных **640px** в ширину (некоторые дизайнеры так делают, что бы сразу подготовить графику в растре для ретины), при том, что он реально должен быть в два раза меньше (**320px**), то можно использовать такой тег для указания **viewport**'a:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=640, initial-scale=0.5, minimal-ui">
```

Тогда не нужно будет переделывать верстку.

Другой возможный момент - если у вас нет как таковой мобильной версии верстки, то нужно просто убрать тег viewport'a.

Еще вариант - у вас проблема font boosting, http://habrahabr.ru/post/214559/

Answer (score 0):

Мобильный сафари увеличивает размер текста, это можно отключить:

```css
body {
    ‑webkit‑text‑size‑adjust: 100%
}
```